# What is the Path In .htaccess 301 Redirect Relative To?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, http-status-code-301

I just redeveloped an existing site from the ground up. The old site used pure HTML while the new site will draw content from a database. Now I need to redirect the old pages to the new URL structure, but I’m a bit confused about how to write the .htaccess rules for a file-to-file redirect.

In all the examples I’ve found, the first part of the rule *looks like* an absolute directory path from the root, but they only contain the part of the URL that immediately follows the domain name.

For instance, I want to redirect

```
https://garrettcounty.us/archives/12262011news.html
```

to

```
https://garrettcounty.us/news/20111226/house-fire-on-christmas-day
```

From the examples I’ve seen (both on StackOverflow and abroad), I guess the rule would be

```
redirect 301 /archives/12262011news.html https://garrettcounty.us/news/20111226/house-fire-on-christmas-day
```

but the actual path to the original file on the server is

> /home/*username*/public_html/archives/12262011news.html

Should I use the directory path or the path from the domain?

I would love to be able to use a rewrite rule. Unfortunately, the original developer didn’t use a consistent file naming scheme so I’m faced with things like

```
12262011news.html
Jan-19-2012-Headlines.html
State-Of-The-Union-25jan2012.html
```

In the new model, I'm directing everything through index.php with

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

so if anyone knows of an easier way to map all the old pages to the new URLs, I’d love to hear it. As it stands, it looks like I have to redirect 70+ pages one-by-one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you old URL doesn't have news title so obviously mod_rewrite cannot create it. However to redirect

`https://garrettcounty.us/archives/12262011news.html`

to

`https://garrettcounty.us/news/20111226/`

you can use code like this in your .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^archives/(\d+)([^.]*)\.html$ https://garrettcounty.us/$2/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]
```

**Path used in Redirect directives:** For mod_alias or mod_rewrite you must use path **relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT** not the full path on filesystem.

Comment: The new URIs will take the form /section/date/title-slug, where section can be news, medical, editorial, etc. The date is always YYYYMMDD under the new scheme. Some of the old URLs have titles, some don't. Those were just a few examples I grabbed. I'm very familiar with regular expressions, but there's absolutely no consistency in the old file naming "scheme". I believe a rewrite is out of the question. My primary question is: should I use the absolute directory path or the path from the domain? I'm confused on that part as everything I've found is a bit ambiguous.

Comment: For mod_alias or mod_rewrite, you have to use path from DOCUMENT_ROOT not the full path on filesystem. You're right it is impossible to right a rewrite rule with so much inconsistency in naming convention.

Comment: I assume then that the path is relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT for `redirect` as well. That small piece of information was missing from every _how-to_ that I read. Thank you for your help anubhava.

Comment: You're welcome, sorry my answer could not sort out your issue though.

Comment: Actually, your comment helped me. The path is indeed relative to DOCUMENT_ROOT. I changed the title to make this easier to find. If you'd be willing to update your answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Updated the answer, pls check.